"ValueError: year -1 is out of range" -error while trying to import data
There are invalid or unexpected values in the timestamp data being processed, such as negative years or null values. How to address this issue, we need to ensure that the timestamp values are correctly formatted and within the valid range for conversion to Python datetime objects.
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd


# Create a cursor object
cur = conn.cursor()

# Execute your SQL query to access a table
try:
    # Retrieve the minimum date
    cur.execute("""
        SELECT MIN(dt_date)
        FROM prod_external.tran_y_register
        WHERE entry_type = 1;
    """)
    min_date = cur.fetchone()[0]  # Get the minimum date from the result

    # Fetch all data from the table starting from the minimum date
    cur.execute("""
         SELECT *
        FROM prod_external.tran_y_register
        WHERE entry_type = 1 
          AND dt_date >= %s
        ORDER BY dt_date;

    """, (min_date,))
    
    # Fetch rows as tuples
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    # Extract column names
    column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
    
    # Convert rows to DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=column_names)
    
    # Convert 'dt_date' column to Pandas Timestamp objects manually
    df['dt_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt_date'], errors='coerce')  # Handle any invalid timestamps
    
    # Drop rows with NaT (invalid timestamps)
    df.dropna(subset=['dt_date'], inplace=True)

    # Print DataFrame
    print(df)

except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print("Error: Could not fetch data from the table")
    print(e)

# Close cursor and connection
cur.close()
conn.close()

i am getting an error: ValueError: year -1 is out of range
